# Chart.js problems with SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, chart.js

I started a project on our SharePoint. My plan was to create a dynamic chart with Chart.js in the script editor webpart. First I used fixed datasets to test the basics.
My problem is, that there is no result shown on the site. The site is blank at all. I tried the code at jsfiddle and it worked fine.
I also tried it with uploading Chart.js to our Sharepoint and refer to the uploaded file but nothing happens...
Here my code:

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js" ></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {responsive:false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work on SharePoint?

Comment: What does `myChart` look like when you log it to the console?